# How can I update the property of DTS node through aliases?

Tags: linux, driver, device-tree

Suppose I have the following DTS file:

```
/dts-v1/;
/ {
    amba {
        ethernet@ff0e0000 {
            compatible = "cdns,zynqmp-gem", "cdns,gem";
            status = "okay";
        };
    };
    aliases {
        ethernet0 = "/amba/ethernet@ff0e0000";
        };
};
```

I want to change the status of `ethernet@ff0e0000` to `disabled` using another DTS file through aliases. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally got to know that `aliases` are not accessible in DTS/compile-time.